Jenkinsfile pipeline with mixed parallel and serial tasks, shows incorrect status
Consider the following snippet of a Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {

    ...

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            ...
        }

        stage('Build') {
            ...
        }
    
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                running(STAGE_NAME)
                    script{
                        parallel(
                            'A' : {
                                echo 'A1'
                                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                                    sh "./runA1"
                                }

                                echo 'A2'
                                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                                    sh "./runA2"
                                }

                                echo 'A3'
                                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                                    sh "./runA3"
                                }
                            },
                            'B' : {
                                sh "./runB"
                            },
                            'C' : {
                                sh "./runC"
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            post {
                failure { failure(STAGE_NAME); }
                aborted { failure(STAGE_NAME); }
                success { success(STAGE_NAME); }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}

If A1 fails and A2, A3 both pass, then at first (while tests B and C are still running), the entire step A shows up as successful.
Only after tests B and C pass, does the status of A change to failed.
Why is that?
Can this be fixed while maintaining the current behavior (A, B and C running in parallel, while A1, A2 and A3 running serially, even if either of them failed)?
